# Recursive query in DB for z/OS

Tags: db2, zos

Dear all I have a source table named "PROGRAM" as below

```
Program CSECT
X       Y
B       X
M       P
A       L
B       D
C       D
A       C
B       C
A       B
D       B
```

Given a Program say for example 'A' I need to find all the associated CSECTs

```
Program CSECT
A       L
A       C
A       B
B       D
B       X
X       Y
```

I have tried with recursive queries as below but it loops for a circular reference example B-D and D-B

```
WITH RPL (Program, Csect) AS
      (SELECT ROOT.Program, ROOT.Csect
         FROM Program ROOT
         WHERE Program = 'A'
      UNION ALL
         SELECT CHILD.Program, CHILD.Csect
            FROM RPL PARENT, Program CHILD
            WHERE PARENT.Csect = CHILD.Program)
 SELECT *
     FROM RPL;
```

Comment: Ad a counter and a stop condition to avoid endless loops. You also might use some functionality to check wether a value is already part of your way though your data as a stop condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add and additional column (Chain) which would contain full path for the current row like below. A new row shouldn't be added, if `CHILD.Program` is already contained in such a path.

```
WITH RPL (Program, Csect, Chain) AS
(
SELECT ROOT.Program, ROOT.Csect, CAST('|' || ROOT.Program || '|' AS VARCHAR(1000))
FROM Program ROOT
WHERE Program = 'A'
    UNION ALL
SELECT CHILD.Program, CHILD.Csect, PARENT.Chain || CHILD.Program || '|' 
FROM RPL PARENT, Program CHILD
WHERE PARENT.Csect = CHILD.Program
    AND LOCATE('|' || CHILD.Program || '|', PARENT.Chain) = 0
)
SELECT DISTINCT Program, Csect
FROM RPL
ORDER BY Program;
```